# User Password change form in a Microsoft access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

Heloo, i have a code below which helps the user change a password if he or she forgot it. Now first he or she must enter his or her username to continue. below is the code.

```
Private Sub cmdchange_Click()
On Error Resume Next
If IsNull(Me.txtnewpass) = True Then
 MsgBox "New Password or Confirm Password can't be Null", vbInformation + vbCritical, "Electporl"
 Me.txtnewpass.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtconfirmpassword) = True Then
MsgBox "New Password or Confirm Password can't be Null", vbInformation + vbCritical, "Electporl"
Me.txtconfirmpassword.SetFocus
End If
Dim Pass As String
If Me.txtconfirmpassword.Value <> Me.txtnewpass.Value Then
MsgBox "Password entered does not match", vbInformation, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If

If Me.txtnewpass.Value = Me.txtconfirmpassword.Value Then
 Pass = "UPDATE User Registration Details SET Password =" & Me.txtconfirmpassword.Value & "WHERE Username = " & Me.txtusername.Value
CurrentDb.Execute (Pass)
MsgBox "Your Password has been successfully Changed", vbInformation, "Password changed"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmlogin"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.NAME


Else
MsgBox "The passwords do NOT match. Please try again." _
    & vbCrLf & "and please try again.", vbCritical, _
    "Re-enter both Passwords."
End If
End Sub
```

Now the thing is that the above code runs perfectly but the password is NOT changed.
Can anyone please help me realize why this is not working despite me being shown that "Your password has been successfully changed"

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` to see errors.

Comment: thanks for that, now am getting a syntax error on the UPDATE Statement, can someone help me please?

Comment: well if i may ask, how do i get the Code Inspections from the fantastic Rubberduck addin kindly

Comment: I would guess that both 'password' and 'username' are string fields in your underlying 'User Registration Details' table.  You need to look up how to correctly delimit string fields within your sql string.  Spotting issues with your sql string can be easier if you add debug.print NameOfYourSQLString after you have set your  SQL string (for your code, you would replace NameOfYourSQLString with Pass, as that is the name of your SQL string).  This will show you the full SQL string in the Immediate window, complete with the values that are being passed, so you can more easily find any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Password is a reserved word, text values must be quoted, and don't ignore spaces.

So:

```
Pass = "UPDATE User Registration Details SET [Password] = '" & Me!txtconfirmpassword.Value & "' WHERE Username = '" & Me!txtusername.Value & "'"
```